# Should I interpolate missing values with the mean/median from the training set or from set I plan to predict?

Tags: interpolation, missing-data

After interpolating missing values in a training set, then training a model, how should I treat missing values in a novel set that I plan to make predictions from?

For example, in my original training set, cat_characteristics, I find that the average number of paws is 6. So for Rufus, whose paw_number is unknown, I give him the value 6.

After training the model, I have a user-submitted dataset where, again, some cats have an unknown number of paws. Should I use 6? Or should I interpolate using an average calculated on the user-submitted dataset? If the averages are very different across the datasets, how will that impact prediction performance?